# Rengine.eval() return null when calling predict()

Tags: r, jri

I have recently started using JRI to run R code/script within Java.  While most of the statements appear to work fine (such as simple assignments `Test <- 123`, and specific functions like `source(...)` `read.csv(...)`, `rpart(...)`, `data.frame(...)`), there is one function that would always return null: `predict(...)`.

Specifically, I have been trying to run `rengine.eval("prediction <- predict(fit, predict_entry, type = \"class\")");` where both "fit" and "predict_entry" are not null, and appear to contain valid values.  Then, when I try to run `rengine.eval("prediction")`, the result is always null.

I am not sure if I missed some library path that causes the problem - please note that the same command runs fine directly on the RStudio console.  The output of my java.library.path and R_HOME appears correct too:

System.getProperty("java.library.path"): `C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rJava\jri\x64;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64`

System.getenv("R_HOME"): `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1`

Does anybody have any suggestion as to what the issue might be?  Please let me know.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are some additional information I missed (thanks for pointing out BondedDust!)

- my rpart() function came with base R, and was imported via `library(rpart)`
- call that created "fit": `fit <- rpart(Verdict ~ TestEvent1A + TestEvent1B + TestEvent2C, data=training_set, method="class")` and training_set was read from a CSV file via read.csv(); Verdict, TestEvent1A, TestEvent1B, and TestEvent2C are column headings of that CSV file
- very good call - both `terms(fit)` and `str(predict_entry)` return [NULL ] from rengine.eval(); however, `fit` and `predict_entry` alone return `[VECTOR ([VECTOR ([FACTOR {levels=("<leaf>","TestEvent1A","TestEvent1B","TestEvent2C"),ids=(2,3,0,2,0,0,1,3,0,0,0)}], [INT* (500, 409, 329, 80, 26, 54, 91, 68, 33, 35, 23)], [REAL* (500.0, 409.0, 329.0, 80.0, 26.0, 54.0, ...` and `[VECTOR ([FACTOR {levels=("1"),ids=(0)}], [FACTOR {levels=("5"),ids=(0)}], [FACTOR {levels=("3"),ids=(0)}])]` respectively - both containing data that I put in to test.  Could this be the source of the problem?

EDIT#2: I tried running `term(fit)` and `str(predict_entry)` on the RStudio console, and got the following outputs (not NULL!)

```
> terms(fit)
Verdict ~ TestEvent1A + TestEvent1B + TestEvent2C
attr(,"variables")
list(Verdict, TestEvent1A, TestEvent1B, TestEvent2C)
attr(,"factors")
            TestEvent1A TestEvent1B TestEvent2C
Verdict               0           0           0
TestEvent1A           1           0           0
TestEvent1B           0           1           0
TestEvent2C           0           0           1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "TestEvent1A" "TestEvent1B" "TestEvent2C"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(Verdict, TestEvent1A, TestEvent1B, TestEvent2C)
attr(,"dataClasses")
    Verdict TestEvent1A TestEvent1B TestEvent2C 
  "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"

> str(predict_entry)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ TestEvent1A: num 1
 $ TestEvent1B: num 5
 $ TestEvent2C: num 3
```

Comment: You have not indicated which package the `rpart` function might have come from. You should post that information , and the call that created `fit`, as well as the results of `terms(fit)` and `str(predict_entry)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will update my original post.

Comment: An `rpart::rpart` fit object should be a list object whose first element is 'frame', second is 'where' and you can look up the other names at `?'rpart.object'`. The item named 'levels' is supposed to be in the attributes attached to the object.

Comment: Thanks for the further assistance, BondedDust.  Much appreciated.  I am actually a little bit confused - I was under the assumption that the issue is with JRI, as the exact same statements could run in RStudio/R console successfully.  I followed quite closely the syntax introduced in this tutorial: http://trevorstephens.com/post/72923766261/titanic-getting-started-with-r-part-3-decision.  Do the statements need to be written differently when calling from Java via JRI?

Comment: I can't really tell what your code looks like and how your Java-client R-server is configured (and I'm by no means even an advanced intermediate with this.  I as trying to describe what should be seen in the returned values. There is a mailing list where rJava and JRI topics  are discussed. https://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel

Comment: Can you please  post your full .java file (with main class)? its impossible to  answer your problem this way

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, I have figured out the problem.  A stupid one.

While I was preparing a compact version of my code in response to Yehoshaphat's comment, I decided to hard-code the values for TestEvent1A/1B/2C (i.e. `rengine.eval("TestEvent1A <- 3")`).  And then all of a sudden, predict() worked. That is when I realized that I was doing this:

`Matcher matcher = PAYLOAD.matcher(testEvent1A);
if (matcher.find()) rengine.eval(String.format("TestEvent1A <- '%s'", matcher.group(1)));`

when I should've been doing this:

`Matcher matcher = PAYLOAD.matcher(testEvent1A);
if (matcher.find()) rengine.eval(String.format("TestEvent1A <- %s", matcher.group(1)));`

Spot the difference? I accidentally passed in String values into TestEvent1A/1B/2C with the single quotes, when I meant to put in integer/real values. Arghhghghghg.

Thanks for all of the help that you guys have provided, BondedDust and Yehoshaphat.  Very much appreciated :)